# Entity Framework: reload all child entities from query based on child entity attributes

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to elegantly load all child entities of an EF entity if the entity instance was loaded as the result of a query on child entity attributes?  Here is a simple example of what I'm asking:

First, some simple data tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices
(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    Customer nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Invoices PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceID)
)

CREATE TABLE InvoiceItems
(
    InvoiceItemID int IDENTITY(1,10) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceFK int NOT NULL,
    PurchasedItem varchar(24) NULL,
    Quantity decimal(10,2) NULL,
    ItemPrice money NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_InvoiceItems PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceItemID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_InvoiceItems_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceFK)
        REFERENCES Invoices (InvoiceID)
)
```

Now, what we want is to query the Invoice table based on a matching invoice item, but to then show all items for each selected invoice regardless of whether it matches the criteria:

```
var qryOrders = from ordr in ctx.InvoiceItems
                .Include("Invoice")
                where ordr.PurchasedItem == "Buggy Whips"
                select ordr;

foreach (var ordrItm in qryOrders)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Order " + ordrItm.Invoice.InvoiceID + " contains buggy whips");
    Console.WriteLine("Full contents of order:");

    foreach (var itm in ordrItm.Invoice.InvoiceItems)
    {
        //this will only show the buggy whip item
        Console.WriteLine(itm.PurchasedItem);
    }
}
```

What I want is to show all order items in each order that contains "Buggy Whips", including items that are not buggy whips. If I were writing this in SQL, I would use a `WHERE InvoiceID IN ()` clause with a subquery. My question is: can the Entity Framework make this happen in an elegant way? I've come up with some hacks that work, but nothing that feels right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty confusing question - but i'll attempt to answer this statement:

> What I want is to show all order items in each order that contains "Buggy Whips", including items that are not buggy whips.

I think you need to flip the InvoiceItems/Invoice around:

```
var query = ctx.Invoices.Include("InvoiceItems")
               .Where(x => x.InvoiceItems.Any(y => y.PurchasedItem == "Buggy Whips"))
               .Select(x => x.Invoices);
```

That query will return a collection of `Invoices`, that have at **least one** purchased item of "Buggy Whips".

If you want to return a collection of `Invoices` where **all** of the purchased items are "Buggy Whips", replace `.Any` with `.All`.

Not sure if this is what your after.

A part that confuses me is this:

> If I were writing this in SQL, I would use a WHERE InvoiceID IN () clause with a subquery

`InvoiceID` is on the `Invoices` table - but the item name (PurchasedItem) is on the `InvoiceItems` table - so how would that work?

Perhaps if you wrote an example SQL query we could help you convert it to LINQ-Entities.

Comment: You have correctly interpreted my confusing question, thanks!